# Getting "too many arguments" error with IF Function

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is my formula:

```
=IF(D4>=98, "5", IF(D4=97, "4.9", IF(D4=OR(95,96), "4.8", IF(D4=94, "4.7", IF(D4=OR(92,93), "4.6", IF(D4=OR(90,91), "4.5", IF(D4=OR(88,89), "4.4", IF(D4=OR(86,87), "4.3", IF(D4=OR(84,85), "4.2", IF(D4=OR(82,83), "4.1", IF(D4=OR(80,81), "4"), IF(D4<=79, "3.9 or below")))))))))))
```

I am trying to create a 5 star rating system out of a 100 point scale calculation I already have.

Comment: It's the problem with a long formula. Hard to manage, harder to scale. Why not detect 5 points? Less than 20. 20 to 40. 40 to 60.60 to 80 and over 80.

Comment: Why not `=Max(MIN(rounddown((D4+1)/20,1),5),3.9)`?

Answer (score 2):

Attempt to break your expression into rows (and base the indentation on nesting) so you can count arguments of each `IF()` and thus find the error easily. I can see it. Can you see it, too? (Update: Now I marked it.)

```
IF(
 D4>=98,               1
 "5",                  2
 IF(                   3
  D4=97,                 1
  "4.9",                 2
  IF(                    3
   D4=OR(95, 96),        etc.
   "4.8",
   IF(
    D4=94,
    "4.7",
    IF(
     D4=OR(92, 93),
     "4.6",
     IF(
      D4=OR(90, 91),
      "4.5",
      IF(
       D4=OR(88, 89),
       "4.4",
       IF(
        D4=OR(86, 87),           1
        "4.3",                   2
        IF(                      3
         D4=OR(84, 85),            1
         "4.2",                    2
         IF(                       3
          D4=OR(82, 83),             1  (this IF has 4)
          "4.1",                     2
          IF(                        3
           D4=OR(80, 81),              1
           "4"),                       2
          IF(                        4     <-- error
           D4<=79,                     1
           "3.9 or below")))))))))))   2
```

Also, another problem with your expression is that you need to use `OR(D4=80, D4=81)` instead of `D4=OR(80, 81)`.

Actually, use single `SWITCH()` function to replace all those IFs.

Comment: I am not seeing the issue when I break them out vertically. Is there an IF() with more than 3 arguments?

Comment: @DrewWilliamson – yes, there is. Please check updated answer. And in this specific case, maybe really try going with single `SWITCH()` instead of many IFs.

Answer (score 0):

*Your formula needs lots of corrections, let me figure out one by one.*

*Reason you are getting error, **too many arguments***.

- You have put a bracket `)` at wrong place, check the last part of the formula below, the `)` in bold & Italic.

  IF(D4=OR(80,81), "4"***)***, IF(D4<=79, "3.9 or below")))))))))))
- `"4"` is `TRUE` part and after that the `IF` is `FALSE`, which should never preside by a bracket.

**N.B** *After you remove bracket after "4", then you need to put a extra bracket at last.*

- And it should like shown below:

IF(D4=OR(80,81), "4", IF(D4<=79, "3.9 or below")))))))))))**)**

- So your formula should be written like this:

  ```
  =IF(D4>=98, "5", IF(D4=97, "4.9", IF(D4=OR(95,96), "4.8", IF(D4=94, "4.7", IF(D4=OR(92,93), "4.6", IF(D4=OR(90,91), "4.5", IF(D4=OR(88,89), "4.4", IF(D4=OR(86,87), "4.3", IF(D4=OR(84,85), "4.2", IF(D4=OR(82,83), "4.1", IF(D4=OR(80,81), "4", IF(D4<=79, "3.9 or below"))))))))))))
  ```

**Now another issue:**

- You have used `IF(D4=OR(95,96), "4.8"`, which returns `FALSE` instead `4.8`, if value in `D4` is either `95` or `96`.
- The reason is, formula does't reads neither `95` or `96` in `D4`, even though is filled with either values.
- It should be like show below:

  `IF(OR(D4=95,D4=96), "4.8"`
- Since you are handling Numeric data, so in this case all `TRUE` value should be written without quotes like, `4.8`.

**N.B.** *You may stay with "4.8", if you need `TRUE` as Text value.*

*Finally I would like to recommend formula like this, which test all values are returns expected results.*

```
  =IF(D4>=98, 5, IF(D4=97, 4.9, IF(OR(D4=95,D4=96), 4.8, IF(D4=94, 4.7, IF(OR(D4=92,D4=93), 4.6, IF(OR(D4=90,D4=91), 4.5, IF(OR(D4=88,D4=89), 4.4, IF(OR(D4=86,D4=87), 4.3, IF(OR(D4=84,D4=85), 4.2, IF(OR(D4=82,D4=83), 4.1, IF(OR(D4=80,D4=81), 4, IF(D4<=79, "3.9 or below"))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Day Dave's answer looks like the best.

If you don't want to go that route another easy solution would be to setup another (hidden if you want) worksheet of the values and use a simple VLOOKUP against the cell containing the value and the table.

I hope you have things figured out.